# Android up to several hours to install 9MB side loaded app, "Deep scanning apps for threats"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I didn't know where else to ask this question. I can't find anything on the net about how android "deep scans" apps for threats. I'm debugging my own android game and everytime I install, android gives me the "deep scanning apps for threats" dialogue. This dialogue can stay up for hours, even overnight sometimes, or it can go away in just a 30 seconds or so. This only recently started happening, but with no updates to my device(that I know of). I can install once(taking five minutes to "scan") then change a line of code, install again and it takes half an hour. Does anyone know how I disable this or why it fluctuates?

Comment: What anti-virus software do you have on the device? Was it recently installed/updated?

Comment: Isnt there a way to whitelist your app in the antivirus ?

Comment: I'm using Lookout. I hadn't thought about the scan being a function of Lookout rather than the OS, because I was reading articles about Android Security scans and trying to solve it that way. I'm not very well versed in whitelisting in Lookout, but I didn't see an option. Thanks you both.

Comment: Definitely Lookout's installer. Had to uninstall and re-install to get the option to not use lookout's installer. Thanks.

Comment: I've been developing for some time and have never had trouble until I just recently upgraded my phone to the latest Android version 6.0.1  It's definitely some new scan they implemented.  The problem I'm having is it won't allow me to install the app at all.  It just says, "Unable to scan 1484" and exits out!

Answer (score 1):

This only happens for me when using Chrome, if I use the Samsung browser it just downloads the apk, then I have to drag the top bar and manually install the apk.

I fixed this in Chrome by doing 2 things, not sure which it was that resolved it.

1. options--security, unchecked and re-checked Unknown Sources.
2. options--security--device administrators and removed permissions from Lookout. (I think this was it)

FYI, once I re-enabled perms for Lookout, I can't get Chrome to redo the deep scanning so not sure if this is a good thing or not.  I even went so far as to uninstall Chrome (or disable really) and re-enable from Google Play and do the full update, but Chrome still won't initiate the "deep scan" anymore.  While this may not be an answer, I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: In my case, I opened File Manager, went to my recent download, and chose to launch Package Installer instead of scanning the app.  That worked.